# Is it possible to give a default to an output port, to allow sizing in the event the port is not required?

Tags: vhdl

Lets say I have an entity that looks like this:

```
constant NULL_PORT  : std_logic_vector(1 to 0);

entity some_verification_ip is
port (
  write_port : in  std_logic_vector  := NULL_PORT;
  read_port  : out std_logic_vector        -- Sized on connection
);
```

In one test, a user's DUT only does reads, and so only connects the read port, and the write port gets sized from the default assignment to the NULL_PORT constant.

In another test, a user's DUT only does writes, and only connects the write port, but you get an elaboration error because the read_port is not sized. So the user then needs a dummy_signal in the testbench (that isnt used) just to avoid this error.

You cannot do a := assignment to the output, as this is an initial value, and you get an elaboration error when the port is connected as the NULL_PORT width missmatches the user's port connection.

Is the dummy signal in the testbench the only way to get a size? Is this changing in VHDL 2018?

NOTE: In reality, my Verification IP is an AXI4 memory model, and in the design different parts handle reads and writes, so the various channels are not needed for all tests, but are needed for larger scale tests that cover reads and writes.

Comment: ***Is it possible to give a default to an output port, to allow sizing in the event the port is not required?*** No. IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses, para 8 "... It is an error if a port of any mode other than **in** is unconnected or unassociated and  its type is an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type. ...". *Is the dummy signal in the testbench the only way to get a size?* No. A package or generic can supply a constant and generic type can supply a subtype. *Is this changing in VHDL 2018?* No. (IEEE P1076/D7, January 2019).

Comment: Ports of mode **out** can have a default assignment. I haven't tested if `(others => '0')` is working here, because `read_port` is unconstrained. Many synthesis tools don't support unconstrained / partially constrained ports.

Comment: @Paebbels IEEE Std 1076-2008  9.3.3.3 Array aggregates para 7 "The index range of an array aggregate that has an **others** choice shall be determinable from the context. That is, an array aggregate with an **others** choice shall appear only in one of the following contexts:   ... b) As the default expression defining the default initial value of a port declared to be of a fully constrained array subtype   ...".  *fully_constrained*, 5.1. NULL_PORT is shown declared as a deferred constant (6.4.2.2 Constant declarations, 4.8 Package bodies).

Comment: @Paebbels Initial value no good, because that constrains the size - and I want the user to set the size. Also (others => '0') is no good as the port is unconstrained.

Comment: If you use a generic value for the number of bits, you could constrain the port and use a function to create the initial value if needed. Unfortunately `read_port'length` is not known in the initial value expression, so you can pass this to a called function.

Answer (score 0):

As @paebbles writes in the comments you can do such a thing when you add one or two generics to the module.

```
entity some_verification_ip is
generic (
    in_width  : positive; -- could use a := <default width>
    out_width : positive -- could use a := <default width>
);
port (
    write_port : in  std_logic_vector(in_width-1 downto 0);
    read_port  : out std_logic_vector(out_width-1 downto 0)
);
```

And when i stantiating you can use

```
.
.
generic map(
  in_witdth => inputsignal'length,
  out_width => outputsignal'length
)
port map (
.
.
```

If the in- and output widths are the same one generic can be used.

Initialising can then be done in a function.
I think this should work, but maybe i forgot something. The example should be enough to get yoh started though.

```
function null_port(width : positive) return std_logic_vector is
    ret : std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
begin
    ret := (others => '0'); --use loops or other more elaborate stuff to construct the value you need
    return ret;
end function
```

Comment: This question was asked for when there are no generics present. The problem is compounded when the port is a record type with many unconstrained elements. In my case (3 years ago) the answer was to add generics in simple cases but a dummy signal is needed for the mode complex where I did not want to add loads of generics. Or you can simply constrain it using a subtype or even a generic type.

Comment: luckily the language gets updates :)

Comment: It does, but the issue raised above was not changed in VHDL 2019